# Remove last item of Stack

Tags: c#, stack

I have a List Stack like this:

```
private ProjectHistoryModel ProjectHistoryModel = new ProjectHistoryModel();
private Stack<ProjectHistoryModel> myStack = new Stack<ProjectHistoryModel>(10);
```

That I want to do is to remove last item of my stack if my stack is full, so I try:

```
if (myStack.Count == 10)
{
    myStack.Pop();
}
```

But `Pop` method remove first item of stack instead last. How can I remove last one?

Comment: A stack is first in - last out, why not use a list or queue?

Comment: @JSteward Well my guess would be he wants a last in, first out collection... (PS you got your wording back to front :)

Comment: In .NET, `LinkedList<T>` has `RemoveLast()` and `AddFirst(LinkedListNode<T>)`, so you can work it like a stack with a tail pointer.

Comment: If you want a collection where you pull out items in the order that you put them in, then you want a [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), not a [`Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) (in which you take out items in the opposite order from which you put them in).

Comment: Think of a stack like a stack of coins - when you take one off the top, you take the most recent you set down. Think of a queue like a line of people waiting at the grocery store - the first one in line is the first one to get served.

Comment: I try using Queue, so I try  `myQueue.Dequeue();` in order to delete last item of the queue, but it still removing item[0] instead item [9] @RufusL

Comment: I think there is some confusion over what you mean by "last" and "first". Do you want to remove them in the same order in which you added them, or in the opposite order?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove them in  the same order I added them, for example if I added 10 items with name 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (in this order), I want to delete item name =  1 when count equals to 10 @RufusL

Comment: If you create a queue: `Queue<int> myQueue = new Queue<int>();` and then fill it with numbers from 1 to 10: `for(int counter = 1; counter < 11; counter++) myQueue.Enqueue(counter);`, then if you do `int first = myQueue.Dequeue();` you will  have the value `1`.