# Dequeue items of a list and insert new one at position 0

Tags: c#

I have a list like this:

```
public List<ProjectHistoryModel> ProjectHistoryModel = new List<ProjectHistoryModel>();
```

Now I have Enqueue and Dequeue method like:

```
private void Enqueue(ProjectHistoryModel model)
{
    ProjectHistoryModel.Add(model);
}

private void Dequeue(List<ProjectHistoryModel> model)
{
    model.RemoveAt(4);
}
```

It add and remove items correctly except for one reason, when I add new item I want always add it to index [0], for example if I have a list with indexes `0,1,2,3,4,5` and new item comes I have a validation  `if (ProjectHistoryModel.Count == 5)` so dequeue runs and remove index 5 now Enqueue method runs and add new item, but it added as index 5, I want to add it as index 0 and go throught all the others. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want a queue then use a [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) not a `List`.

Comment: I use a Queue and this occurs: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730342/remove-last-item-of-stack?noredirect=1#comment92386809_52730342` @DavidG

Comment: Because that's a `Stack`, not a `Queue`. Use the `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the item to the zero index use [`.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `.Add`:

```
ProjectHistoryModel.Insert(0,model);
```

As you've experienced, `.Add` adds the item at the end of the list whereas for `.Insert` you specify the index to insert the item at. In your case, 0.

---

Based on @DavidG's comment, unless it is for practice then it is probably better for your needs to use [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of a list.

Comment: I use a Queue and this occurs: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730342/remove-last-item-of-stack?noredirect=1#comment92386809_52730342` @DavidG